# C# equivalent to VB6's 'Open' & 'Put' Functions

Tags: c#, vb6, put

I will try to make this as straight forward as possible. This question does *not* simply involve reading and writing bytes. I am looking for an *exact* translation between this VB6 code and C# code. I know this is not always a posibility but I'm sure someone out there has some ideas!

VB6 Code & explanation:

The below code writes data into a *specific* part of the file.

```
[ Put [#]filenumber, [byte position], varname ].
```

It is the *byte position * that I am having trouble figuring out - and help with this would be very much appreciated!

```
Dim file, stringA as string

Open file for Binary As #1
    lPos = 10,000
    stringA = "ThisIsMyData"
Put #1, lPos, stringA

Close #1
```

So, I am looking for some help with the byte position, once again. In this example the byte position was represented by lPos.

**EDIT FOR HENK -**

I will be reading *binary* data. There are some characters in this binary data that I will need to ***replace***. For this reason, I will be using VB6's *instr* function to get the poisition of this data (there lengths are previously known). I will then use Vb6's *Put* function to write this data at the newfound position. This will overwrite the old data with the new data. I hope this helped!

If it helps anyone, [here](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/reading-and-writing-binary-files-visual-basic) is some further information regarding the `Put` function.

Thanks so much,
Evan

Comment: Does `Put` overwrite existing data starting at `IPos`?

Comment: Do you need binary compatibility between the two? If so the string is going to be a bigger problem.

Comment: @Henk I'm not sure what you mean by "binary compatibility" - sorry

Comment: Do you want to write a file with .NEt and then read it in VB6 or vice versa?

Comment: No - I'm just looking for a conversion that allows me to write - period.

Comment: Evan, the question is not answerable this way. What is your contract with the reading party?  Is there a fixed (VB6) format or do you write the reader too?

Comment: Do you really put a comma in the number when assigning the value of lPos?

Comment: @Chris That's how it's done in VB6, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you not use a [BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx)?

For example:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open);
BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(fs);

w.Seek(10000, SeekOrigin.Origin);
w.Write(encoding.GetBytes("ThisIsMyData"));

w.Flush();
w.Close();
fs.Close();
```

Comment: Which writes the string 16 bits/char, with a Length-prefix. Fine if you want to read it with a BinaryReader.

Comment: This seems like it would work fine. I'm not superb in C# (as you can tell) ... anyone have any input on this?

Comment: Then just convert your string to a Byte array and write that (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bx149a0k.aspx)

Comment: I think this is the right idea, but it doesn't do the replace part as-is. I think it probably needs a second stream, although there may be a clever way to do it with just one.

Comment: I was able to get this working using just one stream. Thank you to BOTH of you guys (@Henk , @Brian) as well as Martin.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using StreamReader and StreamWriter.

I would try something like this:

- Read the first n bits and write them into a new stream using StreamWriter.
- Using the same StreamWriter, write the new bits that you want to insert.
- Finally, write the rest of the bits from your StreamReader.

This question is not a perfect fit, however it shows a similiar technique using text (not binary data): [Insert data into text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401495/insert-data-into-text-file)

Comment: This looks like it does what I want. I assume I would need to use "False" so that it does not append. Thank you!

Comment: No, TextReader/Writers do not have a Position or Seek and they convert to text.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: You're right, I realized that as I was writing this and revised.

Comment: @Evan: first figure out how you want your string to be written. Multiple options.

Comment: @Henk See my latest edit with your name on it (bottom of question). Thanks

Comment: I won't be able to test this out for a few minutes ... If it works I'll mark this as the correct answer. Otherwise I will give a detailsed explanation as to what didn't go correctly. Thanks

Comment: @Evan: No problem... Thinking about this some more, you may end up having to use FileStream, BinaryReader, and BinaryWriter to get the control you need. Same steps though though.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [StreamWriter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) specially at this overload of the [Write method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf931t09.aspx), which allows you to start writing to a specific place within the stream.

Comment: Where does that 'specific place' come in?

Comment: Second parameter "index" `The index into buffer at which to begin writing.` Which according to the code would be 10,000 for the case.

Comment: That's good, however in his update he said he wants to actually replace some text.

Comment: Edit for that specification was after my answer.